# Remove line selection border

Tags: monaco-editor

I need to remove this selection border from a project I'm working on and I've tried [all different options](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.ieditoroptions.html) from the API to no avail. Inspecting the CSS didn't helped either. How to I remove/edit it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the color for the line highlight in your theme settings of the editor. The specific value is `editor.lineHighlightBorder` (see also the [vscode theme colors page](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#editor-colors)). Example code:

```js
monaco.editor.defineTheme('myTheme', {
    base: 'vs',
    inherit: true,
    rules: [{ background: 'EDF9FA' }],
    colors: {
        'editor.lineHighlightBackground': '#00000000',
        'editor.lineHighlightBorder': '#00000000'
    }
});
```

Note: the background must be transparent for the border to show up at all. So, alternatively, you can also set the main background color as the highlight background color to make the border disappear.

Play with the code in the [Monaco Editor playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#customizing-the-appearence-exposed-colors) to see the various effects.

Answer (score 17):

This can be achieved by setting [renderLineHighlight](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.ieditorconstructionoptions.html#renderlinehighlight) option to `"none"`:

```js
var editor = monaco.editor.create(domEl, {
   value: "...",
   language: "...",
   // . . .
   renderLineHighlight: "none"
});
```